# Algorithms, Block Stacking - graph theory

Tags: algorithm

I am struggling with this problem for my algorithms class. Its in graph theory section. I think I am suppose to use maximum weighted matching. But not sure how to construct the bipartite graph. Any suggestions?

We are given n rectangles of sizes a1 × b1, . . . , an × bn. We want to
build the highest tower out of the rectangles. In a tower, if a rectangle of width w is on top of a rectangle of width
w'
then we require w ≤ w'
. We are allowed to rotate the rectangles (i. e., an a × b rectangle can be changed into a
b × a rectangle). Give an O(n) algorithm which finds the height of the highest possible tower.
(For example if the input is 11 × 11, 8 × 2, 1 × 10 then the solution is a tower of height 29 = 11 + 8 + 10.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can always find the height of the highest possible tower by summing up `Math.max(ai,bi)`. Since you don't need to construct the tower, it is only `O(n)`. Otherwise you need `O(nlogn)` (sort by height of the rectangles).

Comment: Are you sure this approach works, if you have the constraint that for two blocks(one stacked on the other) the width of the top block is <= the width of the bottom block?